# How to force the user to use the default time and time zone?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

In my application I need to make sure, while using the app, the user is using the default time zone and time on his device.
I have some time-sensitive information and I can't rely on network timing because the app works offline (without Internet).

I have tried:

```
TimeZone.current != TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
```

It's not giving me the result I am expecting. Please suggest some solution for this.

Comment: You can’t alter the user’s device but with SwiftUI you can use the Environment to inject a Timezone for the app.

Comment: If by "using the default time zone and time on his device" you mean that the device time is the actual time, there is no way of guaranteeing this if you can't refer to a network time source. The device time is whatever the user sets it to.

Comment: @loremipsum I am not asking for altering the device time, it's about checking if he is using the time zone set automatically or not. If not inform him to use in automatic time zone.

Comment: @Paulw11 I need the user to use the auto time zone, I have mapping to convert it in UTC, and that is ok because my app's primary use case is offline.

Comment: The “automatic” time zone is the user’s preference. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1414388-autoupdatingcurrent  there is no way to get a time zone that isn’t the user’s preference. At least built in you could probably to something complex with location.

Comment: It los likely best to just use “Date” it automatically gives you a time in UTC

Comment: `TimeZone` is really a social construct to normalize the time in the user's area. `Date` is simply a `Double` that represents the number of seconds from January 1, 2001, UTC. The rest is just computed variables and functions. `TimeZone` doesn't even exist on `Date`, but is it's own struct.

Comment: @loremipsum user can change the time if he is not using, set automatically in date & time settings from device. In he changes time than this won’t help.

Comment: That is my point, there is no way to stop that.

Comment: @AnshulKabra What you want is impossible. The device's idea of the current timezone is whatever the user has set in the Settings app. Your app can't possibly know if it's the user's "real" timezone. All possible solutions require Internet access to check with an NTP server or to lookup the user's current location to determine their timezone. Though you could include a rudimentary timezone/location database in the app to get a rough idea. But of course the user to disallow your app to lookup location.

Comment: @HangarRash Even that would be a good check . Can you please share some ref doc for, rudimentary timezone/location database in the app.

Comment: @AnshulKabra I don't know of one off hand. You'll have to search for one. You could simply base it off the user's longitude to get a **very** rough idea of what timezone they might be in. But look at a map of timezones to see how complicated it really is. But again, the user can simply deny access to location lookup if their goal is to cheat your app by changing timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely cannot verify that the current device time is "correct," which is what I believe you're trying to do. Even if you could check the user's explicit settings using some undocumented trick, it wouldn't help. All the user needs to do is turn on airplane mode, set the time to what they want, then set it to "automatic." The time will continue to be what they set until the device can reconnect to the network.

There are some things you can do. You can observe [`.significantTimeChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622992-applicationsignificanttimechange) to discover when the clock has changed in certain cases, even in the background. Keep in mind this is called for several reasons, most completely appropriate, including once a day at midnight.

You can keep track of what time it is when the app goes into the background and make sure that time always moves forward, or at least does not significantly move backwards (watch out for small adjustments when moving between cell towers).

You can keep track of [systemUptime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1414553-systemuptime#) to look for cases where the system clock has not progressed as much as system uptime. Rebooting the phone will bypass this check, but it should never cause a false positive.

It's never possible to know that the clock is "correct" in any meaningful way, but there are ways to determine that it is suspicious.

Comment: thanks for sharing this insight. I will add up those and observe couple of days. Will share details over here.